# Как быть с такой иерархией

Tags: ооп, архитектура, c++

У меня есть следующие базовые классы с соответствующими методами, представляющие собой элементы графического интерфейса: `EventObj` — `processEvent`, `RepaintObj` — `repaint`, `ContainerObj` — `addObj`. Однако некоторым другим классам, использующим указанные классы, нужны объекты, которые могут выполнять сразу несколько действий, например, `processEvent` и `repaint` вместе, и, возможно, их перегрузить. Для этого логичным представляется создать ещё несколько классов: `EventAndRepaintObj`, `ContainerAndEventObj` ... с помощью множественного наследования или композиции с делегированием вызовов методов. Меня смущает, что классов получается много (`2^n - 1`), особенно если ещё потребуется добавить базовые классы. Такая ситуация нормальна? Если нет, то как можно исправить?

Почему мне не подходит паттерн «Стратегия». Согласно [Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)), мотивы использования паттерна:

> Программа должна обеспечивать различные варианты алгоритма или поведения
> Нужно изменять поведение каждого экземпляра класса
> Необходимо изменять поведение объектов на стадии выполнения

Мне ничего из этого не надо. Кроме того, из того же источника

> Вызов всех алгоритмов должен осуществляться стандартным образом (все они должны иметь одинаковый интерфейс).

В моём случае у методов интерфейс, очевидно, различается. (`processEvent(Event&)`, `addObj(Obj*)`, `repaint()` ) К тому же, «стратегию» можно сделать только одну (либо одно действие, либо другое), а тут необходимо, чтобы объект мог выполнять сразу несколько действий.

Возможно, я ошибаюсь, но тогда необходим более подробный ответ, а не просто «используйте паттерн "стратегия"».

По поводу паттерна по ссылке [[@VadimTukaev](/users/18204/vadimtukaev)](/users/18204/vadimtukaev) — он несколько отличается от обычной «Стратегии». Применительно к моему вопросу — это поместить в один класс-обертку `ObjectWrap` по одному объекту базовых классов `EventObj`, `RepaintObj`, `ContainerObj` или их заглушки, и все соответствующие методы `processEvent`, `repaint`, `addObj`, которые вызывают методы объектов базовых классов. Ну и ещё, наверное, различные `isEventObj`, `isRepaintObj`. Я вижу следующие минусы: один класс «знает» про все методы и объекты, невозможность контроля типов компилятором при передаче объекта `ObjectWrap` (нельзя сказать, есть ли там объект `EventObj`). И я так понимаю, если нужно не просто скомбинировать два объекта, но и добавить какие-то дополнительные действия (например, вызывать `repaint` при вызове `addObj`), то новый класс все равно придется создавать.

Вообще, наверное, проще было бы использовать объект  шаблонного класса, который наследуется от всех аргументов шаблона. Однако, непонятно тогда, как в конструкторе передать аргументы конструкторам базовых классов. Разве что использовать отложенную инициализацию, а конструкторы сделать пустыми.

Comment: Ничего не понятно, но есть смутное ощущение, что Вам нужен паттерн "Стратегия". Если нет, то объясните подробнее, чего хотите добиться.

Comment: @VadimTukaev «Стратегия» — это когда у одного класса может быть несколько разных методов с одной и той же сигнатурой. У меня же у класса одни и те же методы, но их несколько и сигнатура разная. Я дополнил вопрос, напишите, что конкретно вам непонятно и я дополню ещё.

Comment: Создайте интерфейсы IEvent, IRepaint, IContainer и наследуйте от них.

Comment: @VadimTukaev Ну значит будут `2^n-1` интерфейсов  IEventAndRepaint, IContainerAndRepaintAndEvent и так далее. Да и с реализацией этих интерфейсов что делать?

Comment: Попробуйте почитать материалы (с переходом по внутренним ссылкам) по запросам [столлман ооп](https://www.google.ru/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=Nq6yVPDaC9PIYMXogdAJ&gws_rd=ssl#lr=lang_ru&newwindow=1&tbs=lr:lang_1ru&q=%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD+%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%BF) и [Linus C++](https://www.google.ru/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=Nq6yVPDaC9PIYMXogdAJ&gws_rd=ssl#lr=lang_ru&newwindow=1&tbs=lr:lang_1ru&q=Linus+C%2B%2B).

Comment: @avp Опять вы своё мнение, что ООП плохо, проталкиваете. Хотя почитать, конечно, любопытно.

Comment: Плохо не само по себе ООП, а безудержное желание использовать наследование.

Попробуйте сначала просто решить (возможно "на бумаге" или даже "в уме") вашу конкретную задачу, основываясь на анализе потока обрабатываемых данных, а уже потом (когда и если понадобиться) обобщайте это решение, вводя иерархию классов, каждый из уровней которой удобно  использовать при решении похожих задач.

Comment: Очень трудно советовать что-то конкретное, не зная специфики. Вам кажется, объяснения понятны, но это не так - https://clck.ru/9NDYs

Я все же рекомендую рассмотреть использование паттерна "Стратегия" - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qo7Hqwypwcc

Возможно, Вам нужны интерфейсы, абстрактные классы, паттерн "Фабрика объектов" или еще что. Трудно сказать. А вообще я, как и avp, небольшой любитель ООП. Я Вам раскрою секрет: даже в разработке на Java классы очень часто лишь обертка для процедурного кода. Наследование почти не применяется. Лучше ФП освойте. Да, именно для С++, как ни парадоксально.

Comment: «Проклятие знания» здесь работает в обе стороны: мне в свою очередь непонятно, какой именно контекст вам нужен. Далее, давать ссылку на часовое видео — по-моему, не очень. Впрочем, я дополнил вопрос насчёт этого паттерна.

Comment: Вы свой вопрос задали 20 часов назад. Видео - часовое. Таким образом, если есть хотя бы 5% вероятности, что оно поможет, то его стоит посмотреть. Причем я эту вероятность оцениваю гораздо выше 50%.

Comment: @Im ieee, я почитал комментарии и обновленный вопрос и подумал -- а  попробуйте объяснить *задачу в целом*, не отталкиваясь от придуманных Вами классов, а потом напишите для  каких целей (в рамках решения конкретной задачи) спроектировали именно такие классы (те, с которыми возникли проблемы).

Тогда, возможно, получите содержательные советы. А то ведь  непонятно, что *на самом деле* Вам нужно, абстрактный какой-то разговор идет...

Comment: @Im ieee: Если вам нужно одно или несколько _действий_, значит, у вас должен быть контейнер/составное действие, которое может внутри себя держать набор элементарных действий. Но если у ваших действий несовместимые наборы аргументов, я не виду семантики.

Попробуйте описать один use case (или несколько), может быть, станет понятнее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я использовал похожее на код @VadimTukaev решение, но только в классе `ObjectWrap` нет кучи методов из всех стратегий, а вместо этого у пользователя класса есть возможность получить объект каждой из стратегий. Примерный код:

```
class IRepaintObj
{
    public:
    virtual void repaint()=0;
};

class IEventObj
{
    public:
    virtual void processEvent(const Event &event)=0;
};

class IObjectWrap
{
    public:
    virtual IRepaintObj* getRepaintObj()=0;
    virtual void setRepaintObj(IRepaintObj *obj)=0;
    virtual IEventObj* getEventObj()=0;
    virtual void setEventObj(IEventObj *obj)=0;
}
```

Для расширения функционала классов `IRepaintObj`, `IEventObj` удобно использовать декораторы, так как интерфейс один и тот же.

Основной минус, конечно, это отсутствие контроля типов, то есть на этапе компиляции непонятно, содержит ли класс `ObjectWrap` нужные объекты.

Answer (score 2):

> Почему мне не подходит паттерн
> «Стратегия». Согласно Википедии,
> мотивы использования паттерна:
>
> Программа должна обеспечивать
> различные варианты алгоритма или
> поведения Нужно изменять поведение
> каждого экземпляра класса Необходимо
> изменять поведение объектов на стадии
> выполнения
>
> Мне ничего из этого не надо.

Вам надо первое и второе. Третье - опционально, не надо так не надо. Когда что-то есть, а оно Вам не надо - это ведь намного лучше ситуация, чем когда что-то надо, а его нету.

Я только лишний раз убедился, что Вы не представляете смысл паттерна "Стратегия". Не факт, что Вам нужен именно он, но факт, что Вы даже не рассматривали его толком. Очень советую посмотреть видео по ссылке, которую я дал. Там объясняется очень подробно и интересно. Причем дается три способа реализации паттерна "Стратегия". Условно их можно назвать наивный, простой и канонический. Судя по всему, канонический Вам действительно избыточен, а вот какой-то из двух оставшихся вполне может пригодиться. Если посмотрите и скажете, что Вам оно все же не надо, и подробно объясните, почему - будем думать дальше.

Comment: А по-моему, это вы не поняли указанные пункты. Впрочем, это не важно. Обновил ответ.